# Problemas con <br>

Tags: php, json

estoy haciendo una aplicación para movil el Flutter (Auto aprendizaje) y me encuentro con el problema de que cuando entro al descripción de un items, me salen los <br> y los

<\p> en el texto, y la verdad es que no se como eliminarlos.

Les paso el armado en php donde hago la consulta.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "ciec";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
if($conn->connect_error){
die("Conexion Fallida: ". $conn->connect_error);    
}
include("../php/funciones.php");
$sql= "SELECT * FROM bolsa ORDER BY fecha_bl Desc LIMIT 0,5";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$response = array();
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        array_push($response,array(
            "id_bl"=>$row['id_bl'],
            "fecha_bl"=>FormatDateTime($row['fecha_bl'], 2),
            "empresa_bl"=>$row['empresa_bl'],
            "titulo_bl"=>$row['titulo_bl'],
            "texto_bl"=>html_entity_decode($row['texto_bl']),
                  ));
    }
$conn->close();
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

[image: Aplicación]

Gracias de Antemano.

Answer (score 0):

El widget **Text** en Flutter renderiza texto plano y no conoce nada acerca de etiquetas HTML.

Si quieres interpretar HTML, deberás de utilizar una librería externa que permita eso.

En este caso, existen varias alternativas que puedes usar para eso, como esta librería:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html